# the .on() method for binding to dynamic html is not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

-The anchor tags below are added to the page via JS.

-The container div `#sC` is there when the event is bound.

-Using jQuery 1.7.2

-No syntax errors, no console errors.

-Yes the JS is wrapped in a script tag and the content is in the body, there are no markup warnings or errors.

-**The only thing I can think of is: there's another event attached to these links and it has ALWAYS worked even after getting my code working.. HOWEVER, I can't find out where it's coming from (devtools and firebug really don't indicate where it's attached, it points to line 1 of the jQuery library...)**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#sC').on('click','a', function(event) {
            alert("POOP");
    });
});
<div id="sC">
    <a href="javascript:return false">A</a>
    <a href="javascript:return false">B</a>
    <a href="javascript:return false">C</a>
    <a href="javascript:return false">D</a>
    <a href="javascript:return false">E</a>
    <a href="javascript:return false">F</a>
</div>
```

***UPDATE***  Tried this also:

```
<div id="sC">
    <a href="javascript:return false">A</a>
    <a href="javascript:return false">B</a>
    <a href="javascript:return false">C</a>
    <a href="javascript:return false">D</a>
    <a href="javascript:return false">E</a>
    <a href="javascript:return false">F</a>
</div>
```

This also doesn't work (???):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#sC').on('click','.scenarios', function(event) {
        alert("POOP");
    });
});
<div id="sC">
    <span class="scenarios">A</span>
    <span class="scenarios">B</span>
    <span class="scenarios">C</span>
    <span class="scenarios">D</span>
    <span class="scenarios">E</span>
    <span class="scenarios">F</span>
</div>
```

After that I tried throwing my .on() function in the console to see if It would work (it should, right? Nope. F*** you chrome console)...  Tried this in console and *gasp* it works:

```
$('#sC .scenarios').click(function(event) {
    alert('f*** this s***');
});
```

Comment: Did you include jQuery?  Did you wrap your code in a script tag?  I put that span example in a fiddle and it works so it has to be HOW you do it not WHAT you are doing.

Comment: Yes all other code is executed properly around it.

Comment: Note that any OTHER javascript syntax errors will/could cause this to fail

Comment: Which line of an unminified library does it point to?

Comment: @MarkSchultheiss - It says line 3 of the minified version, I can't unminify it.  This kind of goes to show how worthless the events tab is though, in my humble opinion...

no syntax errors man, I updated the question to indicate this.

Comment: @MarkSchultheiss if I had to guess it's this line, 2937:

elemData.handle = eventHandle = function( e ) {

Comment: Is your container div id `scenarioContainer` or `sC`?

Comment: It's sC, sorry I'm trying to remove prod code..

Comment: @gogogadgetinternet - the reason I ask is that every example you've posted works - first one: http://jsfiddle.net/Rn2Uw/2/ and second one: http://jsfiddle.net/Rn2Uw/3/ - there has to be something else on your page making it fail. Could you post more of the js on your page? Try searching your scripts for other events bound to those elements and post them here.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that you're returning `false` from the inline handler, preventing it from bubbling up to the `#sC` handler.

Try using `javascript:void(0)` instead:

```
<div id="sC">
    <a href="javascript:void(0)">A</a>
    <a href="javascript:void(0)">B</a>
    <a href="javascript:void(0)">C</a>
    <a href="javascript:void(0)">D</a>
    <a href="javascript:void(0)">E</a>
    <a href="javascript:void(0)">F</a>
</div>
```

Comment: Or just set `href="#"` and `return false;` from inside the event handler.

Comment: I tried both void(0) and # and neither works.  I even changed the elements to spans and gave a class to them all "scenarios" and used that inside the selector for .on()... I'm seriously at a loss here. Trying it live in the browser console doesn't even work!!! Oh and yes I'm using jQuery 1.7.2

Comment: Also going back to the live-in-the-browser testing.. if I use this, it works:
$('#scenarioContainer .scenarios').click(function(event) {
alert('f*** this shit');
  });

Comment: Can you please show exactly what you tried with `javascript:void(0)` in your question?

Comment: Nothing's wrong with any of your examples. There must be something else at play.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using the `click` handler without the on? does that work? (for debugging purposes).

Also, I tend to always bind my `on` handlers to the document itself - as this is always there on page load, however if `#sC` is there on page load you shouldn't be having a problem as you're binding the `on` in the `ready` function.

See if the code below works for you:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(document).on('click','#sC a', function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();//this will stop the page navigating away
            alert("POOP");
            //if after you do something then want to continue navigating the page
            //from the anchors `href`
            window.location = $(this).attr('href');
            return false;//I always tend to return false
    });
});
```